# How can I lock a measure in PBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Im working on a dashboard in PBI and I have the next problem...

I have a card that only have to show the month data. For this I use this measure:

```
Month Orders = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Data'[ORDER] ),FILTER('Data',
    'Data'[Month] = 'Data'[Actual Month]),
    ALL('Data Incidentes')
)
```

I understand that if I use All() filter on a measure, this measure don't change when I apply a visual filter but in my case this change.

So my problem is that I have the card that show the month orders but when i apply a visual filter this data change and I don't want it to change.

I hope you understand my problem and my english jaja.

```
Month Orders = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Data'[ORDER] ),FILTER('Data',
    'Data'[Month] = 'Data'[Actual Month]),
    ALL('Data Incidentes')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead-

```
Month Orders = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Data'[ORDER] ),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Data'),
        'Data'[Month] = 'Data'[Actual Month]
    )
)
```